# WooCommerce One Page Checkout does not display attributes or variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, checkout, product-variations

WordPress > WooCommerce > One Page Checkout

On a single product with One Page Checkout enabled, I have 3 variations of an attribute:

[image: Product Variations Dashboard]

When a variation is selected and Added to the Order, the One Page Checkout displays the Product Name, but does not include the variation:

[image: One Page Checkout - No Variations Displayed]

The variations ARE displayed in the full shopping cart but are not when using One Page. When a customer is ordering multiple variations, this may be confusing for them.

I'd simply like to display the variation the customer has chosen alongside the Product Name using One Page Checkout.

Comment: There is a change in WooCommerce 3.x that seems to remove the variation info from the cart item data and require plugins and themes to use get_name() instead of get_title() to get a product title that includes the variation info.  Perhaps One Page Checkout has not been updated to reflect that change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WooCommerce 2.x, the variation attributes were displayed in the cart as meta data, however in WooCommerce 3.x they are included in the product name.  But this requires a change to any cart customization in a plugin or theme to use the new `WC_Product` method `get_name()` instead of `get_title()`.

If this is a third party plugin or theme, ideally you should find out if a new version is available that is fully compatible with WooCommerce 3.x and addresses the issue.  But as a workaround, assuming the plugin/theme uses the filter hook `woocommerce_cart_item_name`, you can add the following to your theme's `functions.php` (if you are using a third party theme, you should [create a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) so that you don't lose your changes on updating it):

```
add_filter(
  'woocommerce_cart_item_name',
  function($name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key) {
    $product = apply_filters(
      'woocommerce_cart_item_product',
      $cart_item['data'],
      $cart_item,
      $cart_item_key
    );
    if (method_exists($product, 'get_name')) {
      // WooCommerce 3.x
      $is_link = substr($name, 0, 3) === '<a ';
      $name = $product->get_name();
      if ($is_link) {
        $name = sprintf(
          '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
          esc_url($product->get_permalink($cart_item)),
          $name
        );
      }
    }
    return $name;
  },
  50, 3
);
```

Comment: JAKE!  You nailed it.  Oh my gosh, I can't even tell you how much I appreciate your help.  This code completely resolved my (much stressed about) problem.  I am indeed using a plugin, and I will contact the author to pass along this info about the comparability with WooCommerce 3.x.  

I just really can't thank you enough!  Do you like pinback buttons at all?  I'd love to send you a thank you package.  I'm new to Stack, but if you can DM me, I'll totally hook you up!

Comment: I used the same code where a 3rd party theme has customized the cart template but not been updated.  Glad it also worked in your case.  You should mark the answer as the 'accepted answer' if it answers your question; you can upvote it if you wish...

Comment: Done and done!  Thank you again, Jake. You're a WooCommerce wizard!  :)